# How to send soap request

Tags: ee2, jquery, xml

I need to send a soap requests to an external website but keep on getting 
“Failed to load resource: Origin xxx is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin” 
and 
“XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://...?wsdl. Origin xxx is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I have no control over the responding server.

Is there a way to send the request without the browser preflighting the request?
Another way of sending soap requests?

I am using EE 2.9.3 and JQuerySoap

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
var $_POST = <?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>;
var $entry_date = $_POST["entry_date"];
var $billingFirstName = $_POST["billingFirstName"];
var $billingLastName = $_POST["billingLastName"];
var $eMail = $_POST["eMail"];
var $special = $_POST["special"];
var $howoften = $_POST["howoften"];
var $billingaddress = $_POST["billingaddress"];
var $billingaddress2 = $_POST["billingaddress2"];
var $billingzipcode = $_POST["billingzipcode"];
var $billingcity = $_POST["billingcity"];
var $doorcode = $_POST["doorcode"];
var $instructions = $_POST["instructions"];
var $telephone = $_POST["telephone"];
var $produktnamn = $_POST["produktnamn"];
var $produktpris = $_POST["produktpris"];
var $dibsrefno = $_POST["dibsrefno"];
var $billingdate = $_POST["billingdate"];


var xml =
    ['<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://xxx" xmlns:v2="https://xxx">',
        '<soap:Header/>',
            '<soap:Body>',
                  '<v2:subscribeAndSettle>',
                     '<v2:shopName>xxx</v2:shopName>',
                     '<v2:userName>xxx</v2:userName>',
                     '<v2:password>xxx</v2:password>',
                     '<v2:verifyID>'+$dibsrefno+'</v2:verifyID>',
                     '<v2:data>1:'+$produktnamn+':1:'+$produktpris+'00:</v2:data>',
                     '<v2:ip>xxx</v2:ip>',
                     '<v2:currency>SEK</v2:currency>',
                     '<v2:extra>&amp;entry_date='+$entry_date+'&amp;billingFirstName='+$billingFirstName+'&amp;billingLastName='+$billingLastName+'&amp;eMail='+$eMail+'&amp;special='+$special+'&amp;howoften='+$howoften+'&amp;billingaddress='+$billingaddress+'&amp;billingaddress2='+$billingaddress2+'&amp;billingcity='+$billingcity+'&amp;doorcode='+$doorcode+'&amp;instructions='+$instructions+'&amp;billingdate='+$billingdate+'</v2:extra>',
                  '</v2:subscribeAndSettle>',
               '</soap:Body>',
    '</soap:Envelope>'];
$.soap({
    url: 'https://xxx?wsdl',
    data: xml.join(''),
});



});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to solve this, instead i moved the javascript into a custom module